# The trait Deserialize is not implemented for a Get<u32> constant

Tags: genesis, serialization, maxencodedlen

I am implementing the `MaxEncodedLen` trait for my pallet. I have this struct in a separate crate. I use this struct as my `GenesisConfig`, which is why it derives `serde::Serialize` and `serde::Deserialize` :

```
#[derive(Encode, Decode, CloneNoBound, PartialEqNoBound, RuntimeDebugNoBound, TypeInfo, MaxEncodedLen)]
#[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(serde::Serialize, serde::Deserialize))]
#[scale_info(skip_type_params(ProofSize))]
#[codec(mel_bound())]
pub struct InitialSync<SyncCommitteeSize: Get<u32>, ProofSize: Get<u32>> {
    pub current_sync_committee_branch: BoundedVec<H256, ProofSize>
}
```

In my pallet, I declared a constant for the vector bound:

```
#[pallet::config]
pub trait Config: frame_system::Config {
    #[pallet::constant]
    type MaxProofBranchSize: Get<u32>;
    
}
```

Here is my GenesisConfig:

```
#[pallet::genesis_config]
pub struct GenesisConfig<T: Config> {
    pub initial_sync: InitialSync<T::MaxProofBranchSize>,
}
```

When I compile my pallet, the compiler complains that

```
^^^ the trait frame_support::Deserialize<'_>is not implemented for<T as pallet::Config>::MaxProofBranchSize
```

It doesn't make sense to implement the Deserialize for my constant, since it's just a size bound.

The same thing happened with `TypeInfo`, where the compiler said that the trait is not implemented for `MaxProofBranchSize`. Macro `#[scale_info(skip_type_params(ProofSize))]` fixed that error.

I'm looking for something to tell the compiler to ignore my parameter `ProofSize` for traits `Deserialize` and `Serialize`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your life easier, you can use the expansions that `genesis_config` already provides. It does solve your problem and makes the code easier.
So you could opt for deleting the `InitialSync` struct, or just not using it in the Genesis config.

```rust
#[pallet::genesis_config]
pub struct GenesisConfig<T: Config> {
    pub initial_sync: BoundedVec<sp_core::H256, T::MaxProofBranchSize>,
}
```

Otherwise you have to re-do what the `genesis_config` macro does for you.
The struct then becomes:

```rust
#[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(serde::Serialize, serde::Deserialize))]
#[cfg_attr(
    feature = "std",
    serde(
        rename_all = "camelCase",
        deny_unknown_fields,
        bound(serialize = ""),
        bound(deserialize = "")
    )
)]
// Dont know if the other derives that you added here are actually
// needed for a genesis config.
pub struct InitialSync<ProofSize: Get<u32>> {
    pub current_sync_committee_branch: BoundedVec<H256, ProofSize>
}
```