# `The trait Deserialize is not implemented for a` GenesisConfig

Tags: wasm, genesis, macro

I am in the process of upgrading a project from version 0.9.42 to 1.6.0, where the `BuildGenesisConfig` was added and `BuildGenesis` was deprecated, and I encounter an error (`the trait Serialize is not implemented for Test` and `the trait Deserialize<'_> is not implemented for Test`) with this pattern that is present in several pallets.

```rust
    #[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(serde::Serialize, serde::Deserialize))]
    pub struct Test {
        test: // A type implementing MaybeSerializeDeserialize,
    }

    #[pallet::genesis_config]
    pub struct GenesisConfig {
        pub test: Test,
    }

    impl Default for GenesisConfig {
        fn default() -> Self {
            Self {
                test: Test { test: Default::default() },
            }
        }
    }

    #[pallet::genesis_build]
    impl BuildGenesisConfig for GenesisConfig {
        fn build(&self) {
            //DO SOMETHING
        }
    }
```

I found and tested [this](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4743/the-trait-deserialize-is-not-implemented-for-a-getu32-constant), browsed [this](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/d37a45650e112d3ddcc705ef5f642ba075b14e61/substrate/frame/support/procedural/src/pallet/expand/genesis_config.rs#L85-L109) to try to reproduce the macro as mentioned in the answer, but no luck – the error is still present. Furthermore, I also checked that there were no serde version conflicts in the project.

The pallet compiles without errors by itself, but the error is triggered when it is inserted into a runtime compiled into WebAssembly (using SKIP_WASM_BUILD does not trigger the error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```rs
#[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(serde::Serialize, serde::Deserialize))]
```

to

```rs
#[derive(serde::Serialize, serde::Deserialize)]
```

It requires to be always `Serialize` now.

Comment: Thanks, I missed this bit.